# How to save multiple tables in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 tables for example:`table_A, table_B and table_C.`
A is parent for B and C. How can I save the tables at the time of parent table in hibernate.

Comment: First rule when using Hibernate (and thus JPA): don't think in tables but in entities. Next we'd need to see those entities in order to help. Hint: "saving" at the same time as the parent would normally be done via cascading (look that up in the JPA/Hibernate docs).

Comment: Btw, welcome to SO. Please read the help section, especially [ask].

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have mapped tables to Entities, then :

example:

```
//parent

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Car {
}

@Entity
public class BCar extends Car {}

@Entity
public class CCar extends Car {}

session.save(bCar);
session.save(cCar);
```